# including python code in beamer?

Tags: beamer, listings

Suppose I have a python file. 
How can I include in `beamer` presentation in one of the slides?

```
\insertcode{"Scripts/mc.py"}{Python}
```

does not work with `\usepackage{listings}` , which otherwise work in article.

Comment: Try `\begin{frame}[fragile]` for the frame where this should be.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, could you put together a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows what you've tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: `\insertcode` is not a macro defined by the `listings` package. Are you using some kind of template? In any case, please post an MWE as suggested by cmhughes.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

The command which should be used with `listings` is `\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{filename.py}`. Here is a minimal example of its usage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Python and Py-Ramesses}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Python]{filename.py}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want fully-fledged  syntax highlighting try using the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Python and Py-Ramesses}
    \inputminted{python}{filename.py}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```